# Hex-decimals in C strings

Tags: python, c

I can embed hexadecimal values in Python-Strings like this: `\xe5abcdefghijklmnoqrstuvqxy\xfdz!\x18\xfejk`

Is this possible with C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, using the same notation.

```
printf("\x41\x42\x43\n");
```

Comment: Awesome, why didn't I think of that.

Comment: Any idea why `unsigned char d[] = "a\x41bcdefg; printf("%s", d);` prints: `aïg`?

Comment: The C standard says that it takes the last 2 valid hex digits in an escape, so it's using `\xef`.

Comment: Oh damn, thanks, that makes sense, any ideas how I can avoid that?

Comment: Split the string. `"a\x41" "bcdefg"`.